# mapStateToProps must return an object. Instead received Map {}?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js, react-redux

Hello i use Immuteble Map for state and when i try maspStateToProps i have this error.

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: `mapStateToProps` must return an object.
>   Instead received Map {}.

Here is my code:

Component:

```
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return state
    }

     class LoanCalculator extends React.Component{

      componentWillMount(){
       this.dispatch(loadConstraints());
     }

      render(){
        return (
          <div>
            <h1> Loan Calculator </h1>
            <SlidersBox {...this.props}/>
         </div>
       )
     }
   }

    LoanCalculator = connect(
      mapStateToProps
    )(LoanCalculator)

   export default LoanCalculator
```

REDUCER

```
    import { Map } from 'immutable'
    import {LOAD_CONSTRAINTS, SET_AMOUNT_VALUE, SET_TERM_VALUE} from "../actions/actions";

    const initialState = new Map();

    export default function calculator(state = initialState, action){
      switch (action.type){
        case LOAD_CONSTRAINTS:
          return  state.set("constraints", action.constraints)
         case SET_AMOUNT_VALUE:
           return state.set("selectedAmount", action.amount)
        case SET_TERM_VALUE:
         return state.set("selectedTerm", action.term)
        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your state appears to be a map from immutable.js, while mapStateToProps is supposed to return an object, as your error message says. Try to return an object by either converting the map or extracting the values you need into an object structure.

Comment: Why not just `return {state}`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This github issue covers this exact problem: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/60.

You can manually extract the values you want from your Map in your mapStateToProps function:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
       constraints: state.get('constraints'),
       selectedAmount: state.get('selectedAmount'),
       selectedTerm: state.get('selectedTerm'),
  };
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot this is it what i need.

Comment: As an aside, this also forces you to keep in mind exactly what it is you're passing down. At some point, it becomes apparent that you need to split up a growing component.