# Difficulties when try to map the Redux state with the props of the container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, redux, react-boilerplate

I am trying to get familiar with the flow of the [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate). 
Till now I love how neat clean and easy to understand are things, I although feel that I miss a piece of the puzzle. Would be nice if someone with more experience could help me with that.

The problem I am facing at the moment goes as follows.

- I am triggering an action within componentWillMount() of a specific component.
- The action is being created in `actions.js`, its a simple get request made with `axios`.
- The data are being processed in a promise middleware library `redux-promise`.
- The promise is now being passed into the reducer of the specific component, where the whole state and the data that I need are being returned.
- Trying to catch this state at the component is where I fail. I am trying to mapStateToProps but cannot find the data that I need there instead a Map {} is being received.

How do I Map this object with my props ?

I am sure I miss something important.

Here is my repo.
https://github.com/paschalidi/blog-react-redux

And here is my code so you can have a brief look.

### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { fetchPosts } from './actions'
import selectPostsIndex from './selectors'

export class PostsIndex extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Posts</h3>
        <ul className="list-group">
          A list would render here. 
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state.posts)
  //return { posts: state } //****I dont get why the redux state is not being given here.
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchPosts }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostsIndex);
```

### actions.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { FETCH_POSTS } from './constants';

const ROOT_URL = 'http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api';
const API_KEY = '?key=dsklhfksdhfjkdshfkjdshkj';

export function fetchPosts() {
  const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`);
  return {
    type: FETCH_POSTS,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

### store.js

```
import promise from 'redux-promise';

const middlewares = [
    sagaMiddleware,
    routerMiddleware(history),
    promise
  ];
```

### reducer.js

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import {
  FETCH_POSTS
} from './constants';

const initialState = fromJS({ all:[], post: null });

function postsIndexReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POSTS:
      return { ...state, all: action.payload.data };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default postsIndexReducer;
```

Also the action is being registered in **reducers.js**

```
import PostsReducer from 'containers/PostsIndex/reducer'

export default function createReducer(asyncReducers) {
  return combineReducers({
    route: routeReducer,
    language: languageProviderReducer,

    posts: PostsReducer,
    form: reduxFormReducer,
    ...asyncReducers,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note I didn't test your code, but it looks like your reducer puts the fetched data in the field `all` of your global states `posts` field, but your `mapStateToProps` doesn't pick that up. Note that `mapStateToProps` should slice the part of the global state that the given component is interested in.

After a successful fetch the `state` you receive in `mapStateToProps` should look something like this:

```
{
  posts: {
    all: // whatever fetch returned
    post: null
  }
}
```

So your `mapStateToProps` could look something like this (note that this method receives the global state as an argument, not just for the specific reducer):

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  // in component this.props.posts is { all: /* fetch result */, post: null }
  return { posts: state.posts } 
}
```

Also try to debug these methods, it becomes clearer once you see the flow of the data!

Comment: You say, after a successful fetch the state you receive in mapStateToProps should look something like this:

The problem is that I am not catching it there at all. 

Thanks in advance

Comment: Let me correct myself, in mapStateToProps a Map {} is being received.

How do I map this object with my state is the new challenge. 

`const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    posts: state.get('posts'),
  };
}`
Maybe something like this will give me the solution

Answer (score 1):

This GitHub issue covers this exact problem: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/60.

I had to manually extract the values from the Map in mapStateToProps function:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
       posts: state.get('posts'),
  };
}
```

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866005/mapstatetoprops-must-return-an-object-instead-received-map) StackOverflow post.